# How to determine if a number is odd in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone point me to some code to determine if a number in JavaScript is even or odd?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#section_2

Comment: @DavidThomas I partly agree, but I have two caveats: 1. If I had to choose, I'd rather a beginner programmer knew about the `%` operator than `&`, and 2. While `&` is theoretically faster, [it really doesn't matter](http://jsperf.com/bitwise-and-vs-mod-for-determining-even-or-odd/2).

Comment: @kojiro: I'd rather more (valid) options be presented to a learner; plus I hadn't ever thought to use bitwise-& in this manner before, so it's an interesting take. Anyway, since it *is* a dupe, I've flagged for merger with the pre-existing question. Hopefully, then, the answers here (that particular answer at least), won't be lost.

Comment: @kojiro I'm afraid to say that your fiddle is quite useless, since most of the computational time is taken by the function calls. But nobody will use a function call to determine if a number is odd or even... I made a third revision of your test, but I'm on my phone now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing whether a value is odd or even](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even)

Comment: `(yourNumber %2==0)` returns `true` if `yourNumber` is **even**.

Comment: This worked for me, its basic and can be extended at ease:
```const isNumeric = (value = false) => (!!value && !isNaN(value)) && true;```
Returns true for a number and false if not a number. Here's a resource that may be of assistance [JavaScript typeof: Understanding type checking in JavaScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/javascript-typeof-2511d53a1a62/)

Comment: @DavidThomas using & in a language where the input can be a float or numeric-coercible string is a bad idea; this isn't a strongly typed language

Answer (score 471, accepted):

Use the below code:

```js
function isOdd(num) { return num % 2;}
console.log("1 is " + isOdd(1));
console.log("2 is " + isOdd(2));
console.log("3 is " + isOdd(3));
console.log("4 is " + isOdd(4));
```

1 represents an odd number, while 0 represents an even number.

Comment: Note that this will return `0` or `1` (or `NaN` if you feed it something that isn't a number and can't be coerced into one), which will work fine for most situations. But if you want a real `true` or `false`: `return (num % 2) == 1;`

Comment: yea good note about the NaN. But usually, you want javascript to be truthy or falsey, which is why i wrote it the way i did.

Comment: Just to clarify, the modulo operator (%) gives the remainder of a division. So 3%2 would be 3/2, leaving 1 as a remainder, therefore 3%2 will return 1.

Comment: Further to what T.J. said, this will return a fraction if `num` isn't an integer. Which will still work if you compare `isOdd(1.5)==true` (because a fractional value is not equal to `true`), but it would be better if the function returned `true` or `false` as implied by the name "isOdd".

Comment: You can also do `return !!(num % 2)` to get a boolean

Comment: @tfmontague so invert negative numbers first then: `if(num < 0) { num = -num}`. @nnnnnn And I don't know the JS standard library very well, but I'm assuming there's some form of `isinstance(num, integer)` for the case where you are fed a string or a double (in which case I would return false by default, or throw).

Comment: @RonThompson - I've posted a solution below. For negative numbers one can use Math.abs(num), for stings (or non-number data types) one can use isNan(num), and for floats (or doubles) one can use Math.floor(num).

Comment: @tfmontague yeah, cool. This is old hat stuff with new standard library functions for me. Fun times.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I've provided a solution (at the bottom of the page), that correctly tests for floats, and returns true/false.

Comment: the correct, fastest way to do this is to use a bitwise &, like in C, it's just testing a bit, i don't see why all those people use the much slower modulo

Comment: All the above answers may be not fully correct since the minus odd numbers are not considered. e.g., -3 % 2 returns -1. Using **function isOdd(number) { return (number % 2 !== 0);}** should be better.

Answer (score 146):

Use the bitwise [`AND`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29) operator.

```js
function oddOrEven(x) {
  return ( x & 1 ) ? "odd" : "even";
}

function checkNumber(argNumber) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Number " + argNumber + " is " + oddOrEven(argNumber);
}
 
checkNumber(17);
```

```html
<div id="result" style="font-size:150%;text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #CE5937;" ></div>
```

If you don't want a string return value, but rather a boolean one, use this:

```
var isOdd = function(x) { return x & 1; };
var isEven  = function(x) { return !( x & 1 ); };
```

Comment: +1, you're answer definitely beats mine, not to mention that you have the only answer that **does not** use `X % Y`!

Comment: I'm not sure if my test is accurate, but the bitwise AND seems to be 40 times slower than the modulo operator for a fixed number and 2 times slower for a random number: http://jsperf.com/odd-or-even

Comment: Note that this will return "odd" or "even" for numbers that are not either (e.g., 3.14).

Comment: Or: `function isEven(n){return !(n & 1);}`.

Comment: @nnnnnn—yes, the function should test if it's been given a an int first, which will also test if it's a number. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even)

Comment: Why is it that the & operator can determine odd/even like this?

Comment: @Gnuey Every number is comprised of a series of bits. All odd numbers have the least-significant (rightmost) bit set to 1, all even numbers 0. The `x & 1` checks if the last bit is set in the number (because 1 Is a number with all bits set to 1 except for the least significant bit): If it *is*, the number is odd, otherwise even.

Comment: Still not good for not integer numbers. 1.126 will be odd, while 2.127 will be even.

Comment: As for speed, nowdays the bitwise is somewhat faster, especially in webkit browsers.

Comment: @hmartinezd - Your statement about non-integers isn't correct. (1.126 & 1) returns 1. (2.127 & 1) returns 0. See JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cf9k0skd/

Comment: @Blender - yeah, but when one uses modulus, they also need additional logic to check for strings and negative numbers. The `&` doesn't. So while the actual operator may be slower in performance, it does a lot more.

Comment: @tfmontague that's the problem, while 1 is odd, 1.126 isn't, and while 2 is even, 2.127 isn't.

Comment: @hmartinezd - Didn't consider that floats / doubles aren't odd or even. Only integers can be odd or even. Thanks!

Comment: @hmartinezd - The solution that I've provided (at the bottom of the page) now correctly tests for floats. Thanks.

Comment: I do not like this on many grounds. & is a bitwise operator, so 2^32 is the highest int that can 'accurately' be deal with for bitwise operators. Using %2 will  accurately cater for highest floats up to 2^53.

Answer (score 34):

You could do something like this:

```
function isEven(value){
    if (value%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: No need to get snarky, because I program something differently.

Comment: @awm - It seems like _you_ don't know JavaScript. You can't cast to boolean with `(bool)` (that'll give an error) and in any case you don't need to: `return value%2 == 0;` will do the job since the `==` operator returns a boolean.

Comment: Wow, did I really write that?  Yes, that's obviously wrong; should be something like `answer = !!(condition)`.  The point I was trying to make, of course is that you can just `return value%2==0` and don't need to bother with the conditional.

Comment: I find it elegant: 

`value%2===0`

Comment: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` isn't a "style difference", it's just bad code in isolation as it's just extra boilerplate for no benefit. Someone new to coding should understand that you can return expressions and variables, not just raw values, and in JS, `value%2==0` is in fact a boolean expression

Comment: @awm You can also use the `Boolean()` constructor function.

Answer (score 22):

> Do I have to make an array really large that has a lot of even numbers

No. Use modulus (%). It gives you the remainder of the two numbers you are dividing.

```
Ex. 2 % 2 = 0 because 2/2 = 1 with 0 remainder.

Ex2. 3 % 2 = 1 because 3/2 = 1 with 1 remainder.

Ex3. -7 % 2 = -1 because -7/2 = -3 with -1 remainder.
```

This means if you mod any number x by 2, you get either 0 or 1 or -1. 0 would mean it's even. Anything else would mean it's odd.

Answer (score 21):

```
function isEven(x) { return (x%2)==0; }
function isOdd(x) { return !isEven(x); }
```

Answer (score 14):

This can be solved with a small snippet of code:

```
function isEven(value) {
    return !(value % 2)
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 14):

In ES6:

```
const isOdd = num => num % 2 == 1;
```

Comment: When adding an answer to an eight year old question with 26 existing answers it really is useful to explain what new aspect of the question your answer addresses, and if the passage of time and new versions impacts the answer. A code only answer can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation and in this case some example calls showing usage.

Comment: the title is 'How to determine if a number is odd in JavaScript' and there was no ES6 solution posted for what is asked.

Answer (score 12):

Like many languages, Javascript has a [modulus operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.C2.A0.25_%28Modulus%29), that finds the remainder of division. If there is no remainder after division by 2, a number is even:

```
// this expression is true if "number" is even, false otherwise
(number % 2 == 0)
```

Similarly, if there is a remainder of 1 after division by 2, a number is odd:

```
// this expression is true if "number" is odd, false otherwise
(number % 2 == 1)
```

This is a very common idiom for testing for even integers.

Comment: However, modulus can be tricky/undefined for negative values .. be sure to consult the appropriate language specification.

Answer (score 8):

With bitwise, codegolfing:

```
var isEven=n=>(n&1)?"odd":"even";
```

Comment: & bitwise only exactly works on numbers up to 2^32. % works on numbers up to 2^53.

Comment: Yes, @Rewind it's only useful for some codegolfing challenges, not for writing production code

Comment: it's also incorrect if the input isn't an integer

Comment: @éclairevoyant I interpreted the question as "show me all different ways of doing odd or even" and I gave a codegolfing answer which I clearly labelled as codegolfing. This means - focus on doing it in as little characters as possible.

Comment: @KatiaPunter this is a valid method in some other languages but not JS

Answer (score 6):

A simple function you can pass around. Uses the modulo operator `%`:

```
var is_even = function(x) {
    return !(x % 2); 
}

is_even(3)
false
is_even(6)
true
```

Comment: If your results in the ternary operator are either 'true' or 'false', you really don't need the ternary operator. Here, you could/should just do: `return !(x % 2);`

Answer (score 6):

Use my extensions :

```
Number.prototype.isEven=function(){
     return this % 2===0;
};

Number.prototype.isOdd=function(){
     return !this.isEven();
}
```

then

```
var a=5; 
 a.isEven();
```

==False

```
 a.isOdd();
```

==True

if you are not sure if it is a Number , test it by the following branching :

```
if(a.isOdd){
    a.isOdd();
}
```

**UPDATE :**

if you would not use variable :

```
(5).isOdd()
```

## Performance :

It turns out that Procedural paradigm is better than OOP paradigm . 
By the way , i performed  [profiling in this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/jL2uyksa/1/) . However , OOP way is still prettiest  .

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, for this logic, in interviewee someone asked this kind of logic, could not answer, now i got it, thanks.. but is there any benefit in performance by following this method? we could have written isEven(x); etc.

Comment: @ShoibMohammedA : Comparison has been done ! http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/jL2uyksa/3

Comment: -1 don't extend native prototype functions. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (X % 2 === 0){
} else {
}
```

Replace X with your number (can come from a variable). The If statement runs when the number is even, the Else when it is odd.

If you just want to know if any given number is odd:

```
if (X % 2 !== 0){
}
```

Again, replace X with a number or variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
   <script>
        function even_odd(){
            var num =   document.getElementById('number').value;

            if ( num % 2){
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Entered Number is Odd";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Entered Number is Even";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="error"></div>
        <center>
            <h2> Find Given Number is Even or Odd </h2>
            <p>Enter a value</p>
            <input type="text" id="number" />
            <button onclick="even_odd();">Check</button><br />
            <div id="result"><b></b></div>
        </center>
    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Many people misunderstand the meaning of odd

- `isOdd("str")` should be false.
  Only an integer can be odd.
- `isOdd(1.223)` and `isOdd(-1.223)` should be false.
  A float is not an integer.
- `isOdd(0)` should be false.
  Zero is an even integer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero).
- `isOdd(-1)` should be true.
  It's an odd integer.

### Solution

```
function isOdd(n) {

  // Must be a number
  if (isNaN(n)) {
    return false;
  }

  // Number must not be a float
  if ((n % 1) !== 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Integer must not be equal to zero
  if (n === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Integer must be odd
  if ((n % 2) !== 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

JS Fiddle (if needed): https://jsfiddle.net/9dzdv593/8/

### 1-liner

Javascript 1-liner solution. For those who don't care about readability.

```
const isOdd = n => !(isNaN(n) && ((n % 1) !== 0) && (n === 0)) && ((n % 2) !== 0) ? true : false;
```

Comment: You can accelerate the solution yet. i.e., in the final statements you can just return !!(n % 2) , this will optionally make it work with signed numbers (i.e., when n % 2 returns 0, it's false, but when -1 or 1 returned, this would return true). Your solution is actually returning false for odd numbers since it's checking if the modulus return is 0, but should check for 1, and 1 would fail for negative numbers, thus return !!(n % 2) is safer. And anyways, {} (block statement) doesn't cause minification issues and is not present in the discussion.

Comment: @TheProHands - Thanks for the notes. (1) The issue was that the Modulus Version had a typo; it should have been `(n % 2) !== 0` instead of `(n % 2) === 0`. (2) My advice is to avoid `!!(n % 2)`, because (a) it has slower performance than `(n % 2) !== 0` (https://jsperf.com/notnot-vs-strict-not), (b) it's a hack - it coerces a falsey value `0` into `false`, and (c) it's obscure (high-level programming languages shouldn't read like Pascal at the sake of performance - that's the compiler's job). (3) Yes, missing `{}` block statements do result in several issues (as updated in my answer).

Comment: I never avoid block statements because I care about readability, but I'm trying to tell that seeking block statements doesn't result in issues, only in the code maintainace. I.e., using sequence expressions merged with expression statement instead of block statement might make the code unreadable and ugly, i.e.: `if (0) call1(), assign = 0, call2()`, but a single statement isn't bad: `if (0) return; if (0) ;; if (0); break; if (0) continue;`, and anyways I prefer to continue using break-line block statements when I've long-inline conditions.

Comment: type/null checks like your `isNaN(n)` are silly - sure you covered the `NaN` case, but `isOdd(null)`, `isOdd(undefined)`, `isOdd({x:1})` all return `false` which I consider to be an error; unless of course you're only specifying that your function has correct behaviour over a given domain: only Number-type inputs. In which case, just drop the `isNaN` check and force the user to call it with the correct type. Defensive programming is awful. Then your function is simplified to `isOdd = x => Math.floor(x) === x && x & 1 === 1` – returning explicit `true` or `false` values is not necessary

Comment: `null`, `undefined` and objects `{}` are not odd integers, and therefore the function returns `false` - not sure why you consider that an error. The `isNaN` check is for performance (not for defense), it lets the function exit prematurely without performing the other checks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for statement and a conditional to determine if a number or series of numbers is odd:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) 
if (i%2 !== 0) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

This will print every odd number between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 3):

Just executed this one in Adobe Dreamweaver..it works perfectly.
i used **if (isNaN(mynmb))**

to check if the given Value is a number or not,
and i also used  **Math.abs(mynmb%2)** to convert negative number to positive and calculate

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<body bgcolor = "#FFFFCC">
    <h3 align ="center"> ODD OR EVEN </h3><table cellspacing = "2" cellpadding = "5" bgcolor="palegreen">
        <form name = formtwo>
            <td align = "center">
                <center><BR />Enter a number: 
                    <input type=text id="enter" name=enter maxlength="10" />
                    <input type=button name = b3 value = "Click Here" onClick = compute() />
                      <b>is<b> 
                <input type=text id="outtxt" name=output size="5" value="" disabled /> </b></b></center><b><b>
                <BR /><BR />
            </b></b></td></form>
        </table>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function compute()
        {
          var enter = document.getElementById("enter");
          var outtxt = document.getElementById("outtxt");

          var mynmb = enter.value;
          if (isNaN(mynmb)) 
          { 
            outtxt.value = "error !!!"; 
            alert( 'please enter a valid number');
            enter.focus();
            return;
          }
          else 
          { 
             if ( mynmb%2 == 0 ) { outtxt.value = "Even"; }  
             if ( Math.abs(mynmb%2) == 1 ) { outtxt.value = "Odd"; }
          }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you need to test if some variable is odd, you should first test **if it is integer**. Also, notice that when you calculate remainder on negative number, the result will be negative (`-3 % 2 === -1`).

```
function isOdd(value) {
  return typeof value === "number" && // value should be a number
    isFinite(value) &&                // value should be finite
    Math.floor(value) === value &&    // value should be integer
    value % 2 !== 0;                  // value should not be even
}
```

If Number.isInteger is available, you may also simplify this code to:

```
function isOdd(value) {
  return Number.isInteger(value)      // value should be integer
    value % 2 !== 0;                  // value should not be even
}
```

Note: here, we test `value % 2 !== 0` instead of `value % 2 === 1` is because of `-3 % 2 === -1`. If you don't want `-1` pass this test, you may need to change this line.

Here are some test cases:

```
isOdd();         // false
isOdd("string"); // false
isOdd(Infinity); // false
isOdd(NaN);      // false
isOdd(0);        // false
isOdd(1.1);      // false
isOdd("1");      // false
isOdd(1);        // true
isOdd(-1);       // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `%` will help you to do this...

You can create couple of functions to do it for you... I prefer separte functions which are not attached to Number in Javascript like this which also checking if you passing number or not:

odd function:

```
var isOdd = function(num) {
  return 'number'!==typeof num ? 'NaN' : !!(num % 2);
};
```

even function:

```
var isEven = function(num) {
  return isOdd(num)==='NaN' ? isOdd(num) : !isOdd(num);
};
```

and call it like this:

```
isOdd(5); // true
isOdd(6); // false
isOdd(12); // false
isOdd(18); // false
isEven(18); // true
isEven('18'); // 'NaN'
isEven('17'); // 'NaN'
isOdd(null); // 'NaN'
isEven('100'); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

A more functional approach in modern javascript:

```
const NUMBERS = "nul one two three four five six seven ocho nueve".split(" ")

const negate = f=> (...args)=> !f(...args)
const isOdd  = n=> NUMBERS[n % 10].indexOf("e")!=-1
const isEven = negate(isOdd)
```

Answer (score 3):

One liner in ES6 just because it's clean.

`const isEven = (num) => num % 2 == 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Subtract 2 to it recursively until you reach either -1 or 0 (only works for positive integers obviously) :)

Comment: With negative numbers you instead increase 2 to it

Comment: And it takes a hell of a time when n=2^52, and an infinite amount for n>2^53

Answer (score 2):

Every odd number when divided by two leaves remainder as 1 and every even number when divided by zero leaves a zero as remainder. Hence we can use this code

```
  function checker(number)  {
   return number%2==0?even:odd;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this...

```
    var num = 3 //instead get your value here
    var aa = ["Even", "Odd"];

    alert(aa[num % 2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did

```
//Array of numbers
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,32,23,643,67,5876,6345,34,3453];
//Array of even numbers
var evenNumbers = [];
//Array of odd numbers
var oddNumbers = [];

function classifyNumbers(arr){
  //go through the numbers one by one
  for(var i=0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
     if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 ){
        //Push the number to the evenNumbers array
        evenNumbers.push(arr[i]);
     } else {
        //Push the number to the oddNumbers array
        oddNumbers.push(arr[i]);
     }
  }
}

classifyNumbers(numbers);

console.log('Even numbers: ' + evenNumbers);
console.log('Odd numbers: ' + oddNumbers);
```

For some reason I had to make sure the length of the array is less by one. When I don't do that, I get "undefined" in the last element of the oddNumbers array.

Comment: It's because the condition is set to less to or equal "<=" to the length of the array. I removed the equal sign and is the result was as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I'd implement this to return a boolean:

```
function isOdd (n) {
    return !!(n % 2);
    // or ((n % 2) !== 0).
}
```

It'll work on both unsigned and signed numbers. When the modulus return `-1` or `1` it'll get translated to `true`.

Non-modulus solution:

```
var is_finite = isFinite;
var is_nan = isNaN;

function isOdd (discriminant) {
    if (is_nan(discriminant) && !is_finite(discriminant)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Unsigned numbers
    if (discriminant >= 0) {
        while (discriminant >= 1) discriminant -= 2;

    // Signed numbers
    } else {
        if (discriminant === -1) return true;
        while (discriminant <= -1) discriminant += 2;
    }

    return !!discriminant;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return true if odd

```
function isOdd(n) {
    return Math.abs(n)%2===1;
}
```

Return true if even

```
function isEven(n) {
    return Math.abs(n)%2!==1;
}
```

I used Math.abs() in case of getting a negative number

Answer (score 2):

So many answers here but i just have to mention one point.

Normally it's best to use the modulo operator like `% 2` but you can also use the bitwise operator like `& 1`. They both would yield the same outcome. However their precedences are different. Say if you need a piece of code like

```
i%2 === p ? n : -n
```

it's just fine but with the bitwise operator you have to do it like

```
(i&1) === p ? n : -n
```

So there is that.

Answer (score 1):

> By using ternary operator, you we can find the odd even numbers:

```js
var num = 2;
result = (num % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example using the filter() method:

```
let even = arr.filter(val => {
  return val % 2 === 0;
});
// even = [2,4,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for arrays:

```
function evenOrOdd(numbers) {
  const evenNumbers = [];
  const oddNumbers = [];
  numbers.forEach(number => {
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
      evenNumbers.push(number);
    } else {
      oddNumbers.push(number);
    }
  });

  console.log("Even: " + evenNumbers + "\nOdd: " + oddNumbers);
}

evenOrOdd([1, 4, 9, 21, 41, 92]);
```

this should log out:
4,92
1,9,21,41

for just a number:

```
function evenOrOdd(number) {
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return "even";
  }

  return "odd";
}

console.log(evenOrOdd(4));
```

this should output even to the console

Answer (score 0):

A Method to know if the number is odd

```js
let numbers = [11, 20, 2, 5, 17, 10];

let n = numbers.filter((ele) => ele % 2 != 0);

console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using higher order functions, you can have an even and a not(even), which is more readable when writing something like unit tests:

```
function not(f) {
  return function(...args) {
    let result = f.apply(this, args);
    return !result;
  };
}

const even = x => x % 2 === 0;
const odd = not(even);
[1,2,3,4,7,7].every(odd)
```

Comment: Looks very interesting. Can you help me understand the code? I've tried it out here, but I think I am missing something: https://codepen.io/JannieT/pen/rNqzMgd