# How to determine if a number is odd or even in Java script

Tags: javascript

Can anyone point me to some code to determine if a number in JavaScript is even or odd?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if(intellect is even)
{
    var magic1 = intellect/2;
}
else
{
    var magic1 = (intellect-1)/2
}

var magicdamage = Math.floor(Math.random) * (intellect + weaponi) + magic1
```

Comment: number%2 would tell if zero then is even else is odd, this is how math works. I dont have time but I believe: first convert string to int then do the math in your if statement should work.

Comment: If you typed this exact same question on google you'd get the answer faster... just saying :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the modulus operator

```
if(intellect % 2 == 0)
{
  alert ('is even');
}
else
{
  alert('is odd');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the most robust `isEven` function is:

```
function isEven(n) {
  return n == parseFloat(n) && !(n % 2);
}
```

which leads to:

```
function isOdd(n) {
  return n == parseFloat(n) && !!(n % 2);     
}
```

See [Testing whether a value is odd or even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even)

Answer (score 2):

`if( var % 2 == 0){ /*even*/} else {/*odd*/}`

Works for Java, Javascript and any other language. It's a very simple solution, that's why it often doesn't come into your mind until you've seen it somewhere.

The modulo operator `%` will return the remainder of a division. If the number being divided is even, the remainder is 0.

Comment: There is no need to compare with 0 in a test like this. `if (num % 2)` returns `true` if *n* is odd.

Comment: You are right. I like to compare with 0 for added clarity

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var i = 2;

if (i%2)
    // i is odd
else
    // i is even
```

Comment: You're right, why not :) Edited for elegancy

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
var number = 3;

if (number % 2)
{ 
   //it is odd
}
else
{
   //it is even
}
```

Comment: Sorry, as english is not my native language I was make this mistake.