# Javascript Issue Checking if Value is Even

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether a value is odd or even, but it isn't quite working as it should, or rather, at all.

The code I got was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929958/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-in-java-script) question.

```
        function isEven(value) {
            if (value % 2 == 0) {
                return true;
                console.log("True");
            }
            else {
                return false;
                console.log("False");
            }
            console.log(value);
        }

        isEven(3);
```

I get no errors in the browser's console, but it also does not log True, False, or value.

Note: I will also accept jQuery solutions, but would prefer Javascript.

Comment: you are returning before loging, just change the order

Comment: you have to remove the line with the `return`

Comment: also once you are convinced this is the behavior that you want. Instead of returning bool constants return what you are checking. e.g. `function isEven (value) { return value % 2 === 0; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning before logging. Anything after `return` will not be executed.

`return` after logging

```js
 function isEven(value) {
   if (value % 2 == 0) {
     console.log("True");
     return true;
   } else {
     console.log("False");
     return false;
   }
 }

 isEven(3);
```

Comment: I feel really stupid now >.< That worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure value is an integer first by parsing it with

```
parseInt(value)
```