# number even or odd

Tags: html

How can I call a function in javascripf where find number even or odd.

Comment: Show some effort! Google your question and you'll find this (first result): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even

Comment: First, write the function.  Second, call it.

Answer (score 0):

Ever hear of modulus?

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
{
   // I'm even
}
else
{
  // I'm odd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function myFunction(n) {
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    console.log("n is even");
    else 
     console.log("n is odd");    // The function returns the odd/even no.
   }
```

then call function as

```
     myfunction(k);
```

where k is the number as input

If it helps..please mark my answer