# Creating an array dynamically in a template

Tags: angular

Say I have a simple component with a single property which holds an array of numbers:

```
class AppComponent {
    numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

I want to display the odd numbers apart from the even numbers. Here's the template I currently have:

```
<div *ngFor="let number of numbers">
    <div>
        <h1>Odd Numbers</h1>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Even Numbers</h1>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The numbers should be listed as `li` items in the `ul`s.

Also, if the array contains only even numbers, the 2nd `div` shouldn't be displayed.

Is this possible without storing 2 separate parts of the array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211660/9613505

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: angular 5, this is just plain js functions to achieve what you want, but you can convert it to ts easily (if you use ng 2+)

Comment: @Yftach Angular 5.2.10

Comment: this will do just convert `var` to `let` and remove `function` keyword

Comment: Yes, but angular offers a way to know in the html if you are in an even index or an odd index, which is way better than having two arrays

Comment: Write `hasEven` and `hasOdd` functions

Comment: @Hussein This is not really helpful, I know how to check the parity of a number. I'm interested in showing 2 separate list of the same source.

Comment: @AnDrOiD i prefer to seperate templating from logic, and i don't see why not to have functions, but that's ok if that's what Yftach wants

Comment: Note that your markup is invalid since your IDs aren't unique.

Comment: @IngoBürk Actually I added them just for reference in my question. Should I remove them from the question?

Comment: Then your initial html is wrong... @AnDrOiD

Answer (score 2):

[Check this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8r2lb2?file=app/app.component.html) :

```
<div *ngFor="let number of numbers;let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="(number%2 !== 0)" id="odd">
        <h1 *ngIf="i===0">Odd Numbers</h1>
        <ul>{{number}}</ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let number of numbers;let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="(number%2 === 0)" id="even">
        <h1 *ngIf="i===1">Even Numbers</h1>
        <ul>{{number}}</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would strongly suggest you to break the html further and create `child component` which can handle the array logic and render accordingly.

Implementing such logic will mess up your html code. As you are saying, you are not supposed to implement this logic on the component itself which has the `number:number[]`. Thats the core essence of `component` based pages

Comment: By your design, I'd have the `h1` header "Odd Numbers" for every single odd number. I'd like to have a single header and all the odd numbers as `li` elements inside the `ul`.

Comment: @AnDrOiD : in the same `*ngFor` iteration ?

Comment: Didn't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: It seems a bad approach if you are trying to do that in same `*ngFor` loop asyou'll have to write unnecessary code in html(which can be easily written on `ts` file) or without splitting the `array` in component itself

Comment: Your answer works but it'd be nice if I wouldn't have to loop the array twice. My question is a simplified version of my original problem which contains a very long array.

Comment: What if there's no other logic to the array? What if I want the numbers separated only in this component's template?

Comment: @AnDrOiD: I tried `ng-content` to implement in your approach, put a bounty as well when couldn't make it work. i guess there is no other way than to use 2 loops. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988436/why-ng-content-selector-is-not-working-inside-ngfor/50148893. I hope this will help you in some ways as well. Upvoted ur question for helping me dive into this concept more.

Answer (score 0):

Given your markup, it seems you will have to process odd and even elements of array in separate loops.  You can set up getters for odd and even numbers in your component, and use them in the template.

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  get odds() {
    return this.numbers.filter( n => n % 2 == 1 )
  }

  get evens() {
    return this.numbers.filter( n => n % 2 == 0 )
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <div>
      <h1>Odd Numbers</h1>
      <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let number of odds">
           {{number}}
         </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
      <h1>Even Numbers</h1>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let number of evens">
           {{number}}
         </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like the most elegant solution yet. Why is such trivial thing not possible without looping the array twice?