# How does '&' work in relation to odd and even? In JS

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I was given the task to figure out how to determine odd and even. I could not use %. I used & because I found it out on the internet but I couldn't find a decent for the way it works.

N/A

My sample I created was

```
`
    if ((22 & 1) === 0) { 
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }`
```

Returns true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing whether a value is odd or even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In binary notation the right-most bit is the ones place:

```
0 = 0000
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
5 = 0101
6 = 0110
...etc
```

So as you can see every odd number ends in `1` and every even ends in `0`.

When you use `&` you are making a bit-wise and calculation. When you do `X & 1`, are you comparing each bit of `X` against `1` or in binary: `00001` (you can keep extending the zeros to the left) and testing wether both bits are `1`.

So for example 22 is `10110` in binary `22 & 1` looks each bit and test if both are true:

```
1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 < no bits are 1 in both number
---------
0 0 0 0 0 < all zeros == 0  so 22 is even
```

23 is `10111`:

```
1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1  the last bit is one in both numbers
---------
0 0 0 0 1 < 1 so 23 is odd
```

Since the last bit is always 1 in odd numbers `x & 1` will always be one for odd numbers and zero for evens.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Understanding bitwise operators in JavaScript requires an understanding of the binary representation of numbers.

Comment: This was best description I've found so far. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The & bitwise operator works like this:

```
var isOdd = number & 1;
var isEven = !(number & 1);
```

`(22 & 1) === 0` is true and so that tells you that it is even because `number & 1` equals `0` if the number is even and `1` if the number is odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEven(number) {
  return (number & 1) == 0;
}
const userInput = 4;
console.log(isEven(userInput) == true ? "Even" : "Odd");
```