# How to specify multiple conditions in an array instead of using multiple " | | "

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, operators

I have an array of conditions

```
let conditions = [1,3,5,7,9];
let values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

I want

```
if (values == 1 || values== 3 || values == 5 || values == 7 || values == 9 ){   
  return values * 3  
} else { 
  return value * 2 
}
```

can someone please help to avoid writing multiple OR Conditions and get this done within 1 statement?
Thank you

Comment: Hi! you can check doeas value is odd or event like on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211660/14135825)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: you can iterate throught yours values using `map` operator
and then check via `includes`

```js
let conditions = [1,3,5,7,9];
let values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

const result = values.map(val => conditions.includes(val) ? val * 3 : val * 2);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: please mark as correct, if it helps you)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a `Set` from your conditions, this will be more efficient for large datasets. You can then use `Array.map()` to create your result:

```js
let conditions = new Set([1,3,5,7,9]);
let values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

function getResult(values, conditions) {
   return values.map(value => conditions.has(value) ? value * 3: value * 2)
}

console.log('getResult:', getResult(values, conditions));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
const toAvoidArray = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
if (toAvoidArray.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
  return values * 3
} else {
  return value * 2
}
```

or in your case,you can do this:

```
if (value%2!==0) {
  return values * 3
} else {
  return value * 2
}
```