# How to add a class on the interface based on the condition of the returned data in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3

Interface **:**

[image]

How when the index of the returned record is an even number the Row-reverse class is added ?

Comment: It's unknown what your case exactly is. But you can start with checking docs, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

Comment: When I call the api it returns the records with the index attribute, and I want if the index is even, it will add a class to it.

Comment: What is the problem with this? If you need to write a condition for odd/even, this isn't tied to Vue, and its surely have been already discussed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by binding a class attribute dynamically in the element based on the JS expression.

```
:class="index % 2 == 0 ? 'product row-reverse' : 'product'"
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
  }
})
```

```css
.row-reverse {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li :class="index % 2 == 0 ? 'product row-reverse' : 'product'" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{ item }}</li>
</div>
```