# How do I know if a number is odd or even in JS?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if a number is odd in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016313/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-in-javascript)

My program requires me to determine if a number is even. But how do I do that? Do I have to make an array really large that has a lot of even numbers and then make another array that has a lot of the numbers that are odd and then find if the number that the user supplies is in the array?