# Check Odd numbers without modulo operator

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function that returns whether the passed in number is odd Without the modulo operator. The tricky part is that it should work for NEGATIVE numbers and ZERO.

here's my codes so far:

```
function testodd(num) {
  return (num/2)*2==num;
}

var output = testodd(17);
console.log(output); // --> true
```

Am I making some mistakes here? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926475/1745073) answer

Comment: Use `parseInt(num / 2) * 2 === num;`

Comment: javascript is modern - so in latest interpreters will return 8.5 for 17/2. not 8, as you expect (python, ruby etc)

Comment: @Tushar Don't use `parseint` when you mean `Math.floor`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a number is odd in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016313/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you can do it with bitwise AND (&) operator to check if a number is even or odd.

```
function testodd(num) {
  if((num & 1) == 0){
    return true
  }
  return false;
}

var output = testodd(17);
console.log(output); // --> false
var output = testodd(-16); 
console.log(output); // --> true
var output = testodd(0); 
console.log(output); // --> true
```

Comment: `return num & 1 === 0;`.

Comment: This function `testodd` returns `false` if the number **is** odd, which seems, well, odd.

Comment: @torazaburo type checking isn't needed, bitwise operator is going to make it an integer anyway

Comment: Interestingly, this method doesn't suffer from limited range of bitwise operators. An overflow occurs from `2**31-1` to `-(2**31)`, but since the former number is odd and the later is even, the overflow doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 9):

you can use `Bitwise` operator and get same result. does this help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function oddOrEven(x) {
       return ( x & 1 ) ? "odd" : "even";
   }    
   console.log(oddOrEven(10));
</script>
```

For more detail about [bitwise operator](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators#and)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the decimal part after division using `Math.floor`.

```
Math.floor(num / 2) * 2 === num;
```

For even numbers, there is no loss in decimal value. For odd numbers, decimal point value will be lost and comparison will falsy.

Comment: @torazaburo Well, that number literal will be interpreted as `1.2345678901234568e+39` by JavaScript and from the exponent you can already see that it is way above the faithfully representable integer range `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Answer (score 4):

Try a bit-wise operation

```
function testodd(num) {
  return num & 1; // num AND 0x1 checks for the least significant bit, indicating true or falsey
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's already an answer I will show you an alternative away of doing it with `regex`

```
function checkOdd(num){
  console.log(/^\d*[13579]$/.test(num));
}

checkOdd(105);
```

> Would only work with reasonably sized integers

Comment: `checkOdd(122.3)`

Comment: Edited my wording :)

Comment: That regexp seems seriously broken. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not quite sure how valid it is to check a decimal number's parity with regards to Isaac's question. I believe the [classification of odd and even numbers are only for integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28mathematics%29)? Therefore, reverted back my changes to support integers

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks. I updated my answer. Should be working for 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a horribly inefficient method using recursion:

```
function checkOdd(num)
{
   num = Math.abs(num);
   if(num==0)
       return false;
   else if(num==1)
       return true;
   else
       return checkOdd(num-2);
}
```

Of course you should never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function testodd(num){
 if num < 0{
 var number = -num
 }
 int i = 1;
 int product = 0;
 while (product <= num)
 {
    product = divisor * i;
    i++;
 }

// return remainder
return num - (product - divisor);
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, or maybe are writing in some other language.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check if a number is odd or even, without using the modulo operator `%`. This should work for negative numbers and zero.

```
function checkOdd(num) {
    // your code here
    if(num<0){                 //Check if number is negative 
        num=-num;              //Convert it into positive number
    }
    let b=Math.floor(num/2)    //Taking value for loop iteration
    for(var i=1;i<=b;i++){    
         num=num-2;             //Will check the number is odd if it subtraction end to 1 by decrementing -2 to the number
         if(num==1){
             return true;      //return true if number is odd
         }
    }  
    return false;              //return false if number is even
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isInteger method

```
function isEven(n){
   return Number.isInteger(n / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function odd(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    num = Math.abs(num);
    while (num >= 2) {
        num = num - 2;
    }
    if (num === 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what you change and why it should fix the issue ?

Comment: I don't think the check for 0 at the top is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

- Even number

lets take an even number say 6;
6 divided by 2 is 3;

```
Math.round(3) is 3;
Math.floor(3) is 3;
```

3===3 eveluates to true so 6 is an even number;

- Odd number
  lets take an odd number say 9;
  9 divided by 2 is 4.5;

  Math.round(4.5) is 5;
  Math.floor(4.5) is 4;

5===4 evaluates to false so 9 is an odd number;

```
function evenChecked(num) {
  if (Math.round(num / 2) === Math.floor(num / 2)) {
    return `${num} is even`;
  } else {
    return `${num} is odd`;
  }
}

console.log(evenChecked(23));
console.log(evenChecked(90));
console.log(evenChecked(56));
console.log(evenChecked(49));
```