# Understanding Code To Determine If Number Is Odd Using ~~

Tags: javascript

I'm both a JavaScript / Node n0ob....but I was recently working on a project using both.  I was exploring the /node_modules/ folder and I came across a particular line of code that didn't seem to immediately make sense to me.  The goal is to determine if a number is odd or not.

The specific line of code is:

```
return !!(~~i & 1);
```

My question is 'Why do we need the ~~'

(related to: [How to determine if a number is odd in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016313/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-in-javascript) which shows most of the answers using % 2)

I *think* I understand the individual pieces.

- !! is the negation operator (twice) and will give us a true/false value from a truthy/falsey value
- ~~ is a way to truncate a value.  8.234 becomes 8.
- & is the bitwise and operator.

But I'm still questioning if we need the ~~, and if so, why?

I've been using N..toString(2) - for example:

```
4.0.toString(2)
> "100"
4.1.toString(2)
> "100.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011"
```

To try and understand what the binary representations look like.  In the second example, the right-most digit is a 1, but when I plug 4.1 in as the value for i, it still correctly sees that the number is even:

```
!!(~~4.1 & 1)
> false
!!(4.1 & 1)
> false
```

I've read that Javascript uses the IEEE 754 standard, and I've also read that all of the bitwise operators being used here do some implicit converting that I don't fully understand and maybe there are considerations that I'm not seeing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double `~~` is used to convert a string to an number, just like `!!` is used to convert a truthy/falsey value to a boolean.

```js
var a = "4";
console.log(typeof a + " " + a); //string
console.log(typeof ~a + " " + a); //converts to number, but you get (a - 1)
console.log(typeof ~~a + " " + a);  // reverses the previous operation, keeping the number type
```

Now, as you realized, it's not necessary in this operations because in Javascript, when you do [bitwise operations on strings they're first converted to numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10), so the double tilde becomes superfluous.

What I suspect was the intention of the maker of that snippet is that you can't really classify a decimal number as odd or even, so he just cast it as a number to get rid of the decimals, which `~~` does.

Comment: That's a good point that I completely missed.... Odd and even don't apply to non-whole numbers.