# How to print Odd and Even numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge this two codes to run as a working function that print out odd and even numbers.
but I don't know on how to use a `var`

```js
let num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,];

console.log('even numbers are');
for (var i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i += 2 ) {
   console.log(i);
}


console.log('odd numbers are ');
for (var i = 2 ; i < 10 ; i += 2 ) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Help. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a number is odd in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016313/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
const isOdd = (n) => (n & 1) === 1;

const num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log( `Odd numbers are ${ num.filter( n => isOdd(n))}` );
console.log( `Even numbers are ${ num.filter( n => !isOdd(n))}`);
```

- [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Bitwise AND (&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND)
- [Logical NOT (!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I dont understand the (n)  and the arrow sign

Comment: That's an arrow function, syntactic sugar for a function assignment. You could also say `const isOdd = function(n) { return n & 1 === 1 }`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to print out Even Numbers and in the same way you can get Odd numbers list given in an Array

```
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            console.log(arr[i] + "");
        }
    }
```

If you are trying to put your JS code inside HTML Page, refer to the link for more details [Find Even Numbers in JS](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/find-even-numbers-in-array-using-javascript.htm)

Comment: Im using only javascript so i have no idea about the %, and the document.write

Comment: Well, you can use console.log method to print out numbers instead of document. Write method and % is an arithmetic operator to check reminder. If Num%2==0(0 is a reminder) it means Number is Even

Comment: what should i console log?

Comment: just print numbers using Console.log(arr[i])

Comment: good to listen. provide positive feedback if it helped so other community can also take benefit of that

Comment: and vote this post for maximum reach

Comment: tried to use console.log(arr[i])
it says not arr is not defined

Comment: @ArChemPeralta, please check Array is defined or not like var arr=[1,2] as defined in first coding line and if still problem persists do let me know