# Sequences and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sequence

I try coding this sequence:

```
M(0) = 1,
M(1) = 1, 
M(2) = 2, 
M(2t) = M(t) + M(t + 1) + t (for t > 1), 
M(2t + 1) = M(t - 1) + M(t) + 1 (for t >= 1)
```

So this is
my attempt  (but still wrong): I don't know how I can differentiate between 2t and 2t +1

````
function seq(num)
{
    var num1=1;
    var num2=1;var num3=2
    var sum1;var sum2;
    var i=0;                                                             
    if (num>=1){                                                            
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {                           
        sum2=num1+num2+1;
        num1=num2;
        num2=sum2; } }                                                          
    if (num>1){
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
        sum1=num1+num2+num;
        num1=num2;
        num2=sum1;
       }}
    return num2;
}

document.write("seq(1): "+seq(1)+"<br>");```
````

Comment: Where is your code differentiating between **even** (`2t`) and **odd** (`2t+1`) positions.

Comment: How I can do that? I based my code on (for t > 1) and (for t >= 1).

Comment: For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016313/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-in-javascript

Comment: I strongly suggest that you take paper and pencil and manually write down fist 10 (or so) members of your sequence.  You cannot automate something you do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have 4 cases:

- num is equal to 0 or 1 (num < 2)
- num is equal to 2
- num is even (num = 2t)
- num is odd (num = 2t + 1)

In the first case we return 1, in 2nd case we return 2 and in other cases we need to re-call the same function with different parameters (t, t + 1, t - 1)

```js
function seq(num) {
  
  if(num < 2) {return 1; }
  if(num === 2) {return 2; } 
  
  if(num % 2 === 1) {
    const t = (num - 1) / 1;
    return seq(t - 1) + seq(t) + 1;
  }
  
  const t = num / 2;
  return seq(t) + seq(t + 1) + t;
  
}
```

Comment: We need to insert the starter conditions: M(0) = 1,
M(1) = 1, 
M(2) = 2,

Comment: @ha12 Sorry I've missed M(2) = 2. M(0) = 1, M(1) = 1 and M(2) = 2 are handle with the 2 first Ifs